# Exception java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get in Spark Dataset save() operation

Tags: apache-spark

I got the exception "java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get" when I tried to save Dataset to s3 storage as parquet:

The exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:787)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
...

Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BasicWriteJobStatsTracker$.metrics(BasicWriteStatsTracker.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommand$class.metrics(DataWritingCommand.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.metrics$lzycompute(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.metrics(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.metrics$lzycompute(commands.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.metrics(commands.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo$.fromSparkPlan(SparkPlanInfo.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:566)
```

Looks like it's the issue related to the SparkContext.
I didn't create instance of SparkContext explicit, instead, I use SparkSession only in my source code.

```
final SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Java Spark SQL job")
            .getOrCreate();

ds.write().mode("overwrite").parquet(path);
```

Any suggestions or work around? thanks

**Update 1:**

The creation of ds is a little complicated but I will try to list the main call stacks as below:

Process 1:

- 1. session.read().parquet(path) as source;
- 2. ds.createOrReplaceTempView(view);
- 3. sparkSession.sql(sql) as ds1;
- 4. sparkSession.sql(sql) as ds2;
- 5. ds1.save()
- 6. ds2.save()

Process 2:

After step6, I loop back to step 1 with the same spark session for next process.
finally sparkSession.stop() is called after all processed.

I can find the log after process 1 completed, which looks like indicating the SparkContext has been destroyed before the process 2:

```
INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
```

Comment: Could you please show also how the dataframe 'ds' was created?

Comment: While using SparkSession there is no need to create an explicit SparkContext. So you can rule out that issue. There might be something wrong with the way your dataframe is created.

Comment: Thanks LizardKing  and anuj saxena , please see my Update 1 for details

Answer (score -1):

Just simply remove sparkSession.stop() solved this issue.